# How to apply grid system in bootstrap 4 dropdown menu to shape it like attached image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create dropdown menu like shown in image highlighted with red border,

attached screen shot is from this [bootswatch website](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/) (a bootstrap theme).

I tried to apply bootstrap flex utility , but could not get it done, How can i achieve this.

[image: Dropdown menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you look at the code on the website you mentioned you can get somewhere. The class `dropdown-menu` has a `width` property of `420px` and a `flex-wrap` property with value `wrap` when it is being shown. Then all the items in in that div have a class `dropdown-item` with the `width` property set to `33,33%`. That way all the items are 1/3 and you get 3 rows. I think that is all.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="../default/">Default</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="../united/">United</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="../yeti/">Yeti</a>
</div>

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dropdown-item {
  width: 33,33%;
}
```

Something like this. When I see something I like on a website I always go the inspector and see how it is done.